# Custom build using Angular-Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

In my previous Angluar 5 project I used Grunt to build custom components and assets for my clients.

That means I had src/ folder for my basic components and clients/ folder with custom components for my clients.

I used grunt:main to build main app and grunt:client1 to bulid app for my client.

Is this possible to build this app without Grunt using Angular-Cli?

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli have built in all features you used with webpack, grunt etc. angular-cli 1.6+ also have ability to reduce the size of your production build and also improved compilation of your project in a better and faster way. I will recommend you to go with angular cli rather than implementing your own. Use following command on your terminal to create a production build:

```
ng build --prod
```

Hope it will help

Comment: `--aot=true` is redudant if `--prod` is specified

Comment: @Dummy yeah latest version of cli takes by default aot compilation. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @SandipJaiswal that's not what he was asking for, he asked for a custom build, i.e: how to choose some components to build and ignore others for exp. !!